# How to delete string from string with regex and jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder, how to delete:

```
<span>blablabla</span>
```

from:

```
<p>Text wanted <span>blablabla</span></p>
```

I'm getting the text from **p** using:

```
var text = $('p').text();
```

And for some reason I'd like to remove from **var text** the span and its content.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = text.replace(/<span>.*<\/span>/g, '');
```

Comment: Beware, if you're not the one authoring the HTML, the HTML may contain `<span attributeName="blah" otherAttribute="blahblah"..>`. Only use regex on HTML *if* you're completely in control of the HTML.

Comment: Well, OP asked about removing <span>blablabla</span> and nothing else :) If there is possibility of having something more complex we need to remove, the regex will be more complex.

Comment: Yep, I'm just warning the OP. He wasn't too clear about what to expect in the `<span..>` tag. And he didn't specify if he was in control of the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

It's *impossible* to remove the `<span>` from the variable `text`, because it doesn't exist there — text is just text, without any trace of elements.

You have to remove the span earlier, while there is still some structure:

```
$('p').find('span').remove();
```

Or serialize the element using HTML (`.html()`) rather than plain text.

Don't edit HTML using regular expressions — HTML is not a regular language and regular expressions will fail in non-trivial cases.

```
var html = $('p').html();

var tmp = $('<p>').html(html);
tmp.find('span').remove();

var text = tmp.text();
```

Comment: I didn't want to delete the span node from DOM. I needed the text from p (in variable) without span and its content.

Comment: @sunpietro In that case you could walk `p.childNodes` and concatenate their `.textContent`, skipping nodes with `.tagName=='SPAN'` (that's raw DOM, I'm not sure what that is in jQueryish).

Answer (score 2):

to remove the unwanted whitespace before the `<span>` use

```
text = text.replace(/\s*<span>.*<\/span>/g, '');
```

leaving you with

```
<p>Text wanted</p>
```